# How to Show User Location and Store location with distance between user and store in google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have list of stores which contains latitude and longitude.here i have particuler user latitude and longitude and i have calculatd distance between store and user.everything working fine. i that list i have one button(map) when i click that button one div should come with google map.In that Google map i need to show two markers.which is user(user current location marker) and another one is store(store location marker) .and i need to show distance between store and user. pls some one help me out to move forward i have been tried 3 days .i have added my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/21/

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {
    //$scope.query = " Regular Service,Hardware Faults,overall maintenance";
    $scope.dealers = [{
        
        S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.93489905",
  S_Longitude: "77.57070772",
  S_clocation: ""
    }, {
       
        S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia",
        Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
        S_Services: "Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.9599264",
  S_Longitude: "77.5924983",
  S_clocation: ""
    }, {
        
        S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "sun mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.911229",
  S_Longitude: "77.519281",
  S_clocation:""
  },
 {
        
        S_Email_id: "super@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "ragu mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.909999",
  S_Longitude: "77.506871",
  S_clocation: ""
  }
    ]
 var _lat1 =12.904778 ;
 var _lon1 =77.585680;
 
              var d = $scope.dealers.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < d; i++) {



                            var _lat2 = $scope.dealers[i].S_Latitude;
                            var _lon2 = $scope.dealers[i].S_Longitude;

                            //--------------------------------------distance calculation-------------------------------------
                            function _getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
                                var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in kilometers
                                var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
                                var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
                                var a =
                                    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                                    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
                                    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
                                var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
                                var d = R * c; // Distance in KM
                                return d;
                            }

                            function deg2rad(deg) {
                                return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
                            }



                            // precise value
                            var _d = "Precise value: " + _getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(_lat1, _lon1, _lat2, _lon2);




                            _d = Math.round(_getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(_lat1, _lon1, _lat2, _lon2) * 100) / 100;

             $scope.dealers[i].distance = _d;
       console.log(_d);

                            

                            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        }
 }
)
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
        <label>Case sensitive Search on Label</label><br>
        <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name" />
        
        
            <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">
                          
                {{dealer.Store_Name}}<br>
    {{dealer.S_Email_id}}<br>
    {{dealer.S_clocation}}
                Distance: {{dealer.distance}}<br>
                <input type="button" name="map" id="map" value="map"><br><br>
    </div><br><br><br>
                
    
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what exactly you want ? Do you want show distance in km ? Or just want to place a line between two markers ? Please brief your exact requirement. That will be more helpful.

Comment: hen i click map button it's should show one map with two markers(user,store) with line and should display distance

Comment: Okay.. Give me few minute I will help you.

Comment: okey can you pls add fiddle

Comment: can you pls explain me how to do this.otherwise help me out to move forward

Comment: I am creating demo with angular-google-maps. I personally find it very useful https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps

Comment: for this question i need answer can you pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle for your question.

> I have took reference from
> http://ngmap.github.io/#/directions-with-custom-marker.html
>
> I personally found it easy to implement.

**Fiddle : http://plnkr.co/edit/A6BUeeGwEDmjIngRHhSE?p=preview

If fiddle not work :

**index.html :**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<style>
    /* Styles go here */

    .custom-marker {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: #7F7F7F solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .custom-marker:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 6px 0;
    border-color: #fff transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -6px;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 50%;
    }
    .custom-marker:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 6px 0;
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: -6px;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 50%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
      <label>Case sensitive Search on Label</label><br>
      <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name" />
      <div>
        <ng-map zoom="12" center="{{lat}}, {{lon}}">
          
          <directions
          draggable="true"
          panel="directions-panel"
          travel-mode="DRIVING"
          origin="{{lat}}, {{lon}}"
          destination="{{lat1}}, {{lon1}}">
        </directions>
        
          
        </ng-map>
        <br><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
      <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">
        {{dealer.Store_Name}}<br>
                {{dealer.S_Email_id}}<br>
                {{dealer.S_clocation}}
        Distance: {{dealer.distance}}<br>
        <input type="button" name="map" id="map" value="map" ng-click="updateMap(dealer);"><br><br>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br><br><br>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js :**

// Code goes here

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap'])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {
      var _lat1 =12.904778 ;
        var _lon1 =77.585680;
        $scope.lat = _lat1;
        $scope.lon = _lon1;
      $scope.positions = [{pos:[$scope.lat, $scope.lon],name:"User"}];
      $scope.center = [$scope.lat, $scope.lon];
      
      //$scope.query = " Regular Service,Hardware Faults,overall maintenance";
      $scope.viewMap = false;
      $scope.updateMap = function(dealer) {
        $scope.lat1 = dealer.S_Latitude;
          $scope.lon1 = dealer.S_Longitude;
        $scope.positions = [{pos:[$scope.lat, $scope.lon],name:"User"}, {pos:[dealer.S_Latitude, dealer.S_Longitude],name:"Store"}];
        $scope.viewMap = true;
        $scope.path = [[$scope.lat, $scope.lon], [dealer.S_Latitude, dealer.S_Longitude]];
      }
    
    $scope.dealers = [{
        
        S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        S_Latitude: "12.93489905",
        S_Longitude: "77.57070772",
        S_clocation: ""
    }, {
       
        S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia",
        Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
        S_Services: "Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
        S_Latitude: "12.9599264",
        S_Longitude: "77.5924983",
        S_clocation: ""
    }, {
        
        S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "sun mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        S_Latitude: "12.911229",
        S_Longitude: "77.519281",
        S_clocation:""
        },
    {
        
        S_Email_id: "super@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "ragu mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        S_Latitude: "12.909999",
        S_Longitude: "77.506871",
        S_clocation: ""
        }
    ]

  var d = $scope.dealers.length;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < d; i++) {



                            var _lat2 = $scope.dealers[i].S_Latitude;
                            var _lon2 = $scope.dealers[i].S_Longitude;

                            //--------------------------------------distance calculation-------------------------------------
                            function _getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
                                var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in kilometers
                                var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
                                var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
                                var a =
                                    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                                    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
                                    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
                                var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
                                var d = R * c; // Distance in KM
                                return d;
                            }

                            function deg2rad(deg) {
                                return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
                            }



                            // precise value
                            var _d = "Precise value: " + _getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(_lat1, _lon1, _lat2, _lon2);




                            _d = Math.round(_getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(_lat1, _lon1, _lat2, _lon2) * 100) / 100;

                            $scope.dealers[i].distance = _d;
                            console.log(_d);

                            

                            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        }

    }
)
```

Hope this will help you !

Cheers,
James

Comment: pls check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/21/ .i have user,store latitude and longitude,i have calculated between the distance.here in that list  i have map button when ever i click that map button map should show marker with line and distance

Comment: @sree, I checked this when you post the question. Did you make any changes into it ? I can give you hint and all required is to put a map which I created into a div and on button click you will have to show/hide the map.That's all left.  As I told you if I get time I will update your fiddle. Let me know if you don't understand anything.

Comment: i am new to this google map. pls update my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rpbn6u23/21/

Comment: can you pls help me out i am not able to solve this since 4 days

Comment: I will try to udpate fiddle by today.

Comment: pls do it bcoz i cant able to solve this thanks in advance

Comment: @martin, I have updated the post. Please find it out and let me know if update required.

Comment: how can i add stores information in that infoe window.for example i have clicked Adtiya Samsung Store map button .dealer marker info window should show Adtiya Samsung Store,aditiya@gmail.com,samsung,Adtiya Samsung Store,Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults, 14, Netaji Rd, NR Colony, Basavanagudi, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560004, India

Comment: how can i change the marker icon and i want to add store deatils in that pop up window.or example i have clicked Adtiya Samsung Store map button .dealer marker info window should show Adtiya Samsung Store,aditiya@gmail.com,samsung,Adtiya Samsung Store,Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults, 14, Netaji Rd, NR Colony, Basavanagudi, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560004, India

Comment: Have you try to look the reference link I gave to you ? http://ngmap.github.io/#/directions-with-custom-marker.html it has all the demo you exactly wants. I guess you are a good learner you can implement the logic according to your requirement from ngMap directive.

Comment: just i want to add store details in that marker info window